# Error: socket hang up using putStream method in msgraph-sdk-javascript (nodejs)

Tags: javascript, node.js, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I'm using the putStream method to upload files to OneDrive programmatically in a nodejs project.
Everything works correctly while the files are not too big. For example, files under 100kb work without problems.

However, when I try to upload a file of about 800kb, after a considerable waiting time, it returns the following error:

```
Error: socket hang up
  at createHangUpError (_http_client.js:331:15)
  at Socket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:423:23)
  at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
  at Socket.emit (events.js:208:7)
  at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1056:12)
  at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
  at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9) 
  code: 'ECONNRESET'
```

Then I paste an extract of the code involved in the upload. Before it, I only check that there is a certain destination path:

```
[...]
.then(function(response)
{
    var stream = fs.createReadStream(self.files[0].path);
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject)
    {
        client.api(ep + ':' + realxlspath + ':/content')
            .putStream(stream, function(err)
            {
                if (err) reject(err);
                else resolve(true);
            });
    });
})
[...]
```

Again, there is no problem handling the rest of the API, or uploading files of about 100kb maximum.

[According to the documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/driveitem_put_content) of the Microsoft Graph API, I should not have problems uploading files up to 4Mb. I am using the official SDK for [JavaScript/NodeJs](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-javascript).

Can someone tell me what's going on?

Comment: I suspect the socket is being closed because of timeout. Have you tried updating the timeout for `putstream` to be a greater duration?

Comment: Unfortunately, SDK don't exposes a timeout method or property (https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-javascript/issues/39). Anyway, in my tests I hacked the SDK appending a line with `req.timeout({ response: 60000 * 15, deadline: 60000 * 15 });` in GraphRequest.js:225.

The error is still there. Curiously, it happens after two or three minutes of waiting. The file is always truncated to 128kb in OneDrive. Could the server be hanging the connection?